# Can we omit the preposition FOR when show how long something has been happening/has happened and so on

Tags: prepositions, present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

Came across two sentences w/o *for*  and became curious if it's correct and appropriate.

> They have been together __ four years.

> I have been waiting __ two hours, can't believe she stood me up.

Comment: Yes.  See Jon Purdy's answer here:  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60566/when-can-i-omit-for-before-a-time-duration

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it is very common.**

The right side of [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=waiting+for+*+hours%2Cwaiting+*+hours&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=0) shows some of the top hits from books including and excluding *for*:

[image]

**Either way, it will be understood.**